# ECG healthcare monitoring system in android

Tags: android

i just need to do ECG healthcare monitoring system in android.I don't have any idea regarding that. what are the necessary things & how could i do that.?Pls help me.Its urgent.Thanks in advance.
Rgds,
Sudhir.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider 1. asking a less vague question,  2. not showing up on a site where you're asking people to volunteer their time and expertise to help you and making arrogant demands by saying "its urgent"

Comment: Do you have an understanding of the problem domain? When it comes to healthcare systems, you really, really, really need to know what you're doing, and I commend you for asking for help. At the same time, however, your question is sorely lacking in details, which shows that you haven't really thought through this whole thing and haven't done any kind of research. That and the "please help me it's urgent" tone with respect to healthcare systems like an ECG monitoring Android device quite frankly makes me anxious.

Comment: I'm just asking what are the steps i have to take up(i.e)How could i connect with sensors and method to convert analog signals from sensor into digital signals which frwd to android device like that only i need. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other contributors - you really need to research your area from the ground up. If I was tasked with this, I'd look at what an ECG is actually measuring, what the scales would be on the axes of the output graph (I'm guessing there's a requirement for a graph-type output) and I'd look at the specifications of the sensors - what do they output? I'm guessing you may need to write an interface (or get a hold of an interface, possibly from the sensor manufacturer's) - that might be a good place to start. Hope this helps.